# Need Regex for finding a special tag

Tags: php, regex, arrays, string

It's kind of a for an BB-Code... And I'm down to this:

```
preg_match_all('/\imgid=\[([^"*]*)\*/', '\1.\]', $html, $found);
```

OK so what should it do? Returning an Array with all matched Values ;)...

So if my String is: "I am an amazing Image: imgid=[15] and this is even more amazing: imgid=[16]" it should return an array with the values 15 and 16.

Thanks

Comment: Actually the above code doesn't throw any error - it's just that it returns "Null"

Comment: Looks like I tested with an earlier version of your code in question. The problem with the wrong parameter usage of the function remains: http://php.net/preg_match_all - that is first of all a PHP problem, not a regex one. Please review.

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/LstTAE

Comment: -.- my mistake... didn't look at the, all the time... It's getting late anyways thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression

```
/\imgid=/[([^"*]*)\*/', '/]\1.
         ^ error
```

has an error:

> Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier '['

You should take care that you are making use of proper use of [delimiters](http://php.net/regexp.reference.delimiters). In your case I'd assume you meant `\` instead of `/` before the `[`.

Also as you only have numbers as IDs in your example, I would use `\d+` for inside the brackets instead what you use in there.

Comment: Well I changed it in the main post - as I don't use regex too often I am unfortunally not very good in this but yes of course you where right with the \ instead of / - still it doesn't work :D

Comment: Well, you first of all have a syntax error in your PHP code. Check the number of parameters, you don't want to do a replacement with `preg_match_all` but capture matches. See http://php.net/preg_match_all - So apart from the regex pattern you're looking for, you should fix the syntax error first. That's PHP code I think you're more fluent with. Fix your code first please ;)